# plotting two DataFrame.value_counts() in a single histogram

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I want to plot in a single histogram two different dataframes (only one column from each).

```
d1 = {'Size': ['Big', 'Big', 'Normal','Big']}
df1 = pd.DataFrame(data=d1)

d2 = {'Size': ['Small','Normal','Normal','Normal', 'Small', 'Big', 'Big', 'Normal','Big']}
df2 = pd.DataFrame(data=d2)

#Plotting in one histogram
df1['Size'].value_counts().plot.bar(label = "df1")
df2['Size'].value_counts().plot.bar(label = "df2", alpha = 0.2,color='purple')

plt.legend(loc='upper right')
plt.show()
```

The issue is that in the x-axis of the histogram is only correct for df2. For df1 there should be 3 values of 'big' and 1 value of 'normal':

[histogram of df1 and df2.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mafbo.png)

I have tried multiple ways of generating the plot and this is the closest I got to what I want, which is both dataframes in the same histogram, with different colors.

Ideally they would be side to side, but I didn't manage to find how, and 'stacked = False' doesn't work here.

Any help is welcome. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can [`reindex`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.reindex.html) on explicit X-values:

```
x = ['Small', 'Normal', 'Big']
df1['Size'].value_counts().reindex(x).plot.bar(label = "df1")
df2['Size'].value_counts().reindex(x).plot.bar(label = "df2", alpha = 0.2,color='purple')
```

Output:

[image: pandas aligned bar plot]

Another option:

```
(pd.concat({'df1': df1, 'df2': df2})['Size']
   .groupby(level=0).value_counts()
   .unstack(0)
   .plot.bar()
)
```

Output:

[image: pandas bar plot]

Comment: Hi, thank you for taking the time!

The second option is ideal. I had to tweak it to avoid an AttributeError ('DataFrameGroupBy' object has no attribute 'value_counts'). This is how it looks for me:

df3 = pd.concat({'df1': df1, 'df2': df2})

df3['Size'].groupby(level=0).value_counts().unstack(0).plot.bar()

Answer (score 0):

You can also try `plotly` which produces interactive graphs. That is we can hover over the plots and see exact data values and other information.

```
import plotly.graph_objects as go
classes=['Small', 'Normal', 'Large']
#classes=df2.Size.unique()  (better to use this)

fig = go.Figure(data=[
    go.Bar(name='df1', x=classes, y=df1.value_counts()),
    go.Bar(name='df2', x=classes, y=df2.value_counts())
])
# Change the bar mode
fig.update_layout(barmode='group')
fig.show()
```

Output:
[image]

Comment: Thanks for your time! I didn't know plotly, looks like a beast. I'll dive in! Cheers